# What is the right function family to fit these curves?

Tags: functions, parameter-estimation

I have a bunch of data that im trying to fit but I cant find the right function family.
Its like a big V with a curved bottom and linear sides. The function family should be able to fit all of the data below.
[image: data_graph]

The fit above was an auto fit with a parabola. As you can see the ends of the data are more linear than the ends of the parabola. The fit below is a manual fit with the function sec^2. Its hard to do auto fit with sec^2 because its non-continuous. The fit is similar to the parabola: the ends of the sec^2 function are more curved than the data. The data was not generated by a computer, but it should still be pretty accurate. Thats why I'm pretty sure there is a better function family out there considering these functions dont look perfect.
[image: sec squared]

Comment: What do the data describe?  The physical situation might shed some light on what functions make most sense.

Comment: Looks like a catenary: try y= a*tanh(x/a)

Comment: Might want to try a hyperbola $\frac{y^2}{b^2} - \frac{x^2}{a^2} = 1$

Comment: @insipidintegrator are you sure its not cosh?

Comment: Yikes I messed up yes it is cosh @Imightbehigh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ends get linear, you can try to fit against a hyperbola

$$h(x) = a\sqrt{b^2+(x-x_0)^2}+c$$

- For large $x$, the function behaves like $$h(x)\approx a|x-x_0|+c$$ thus linear with slope $-a$ for large negative $x$ and slope $a$ for large positive $x$.
- The two linear asymptotes meet at $(x_0, c)$, so you can determine $c$ graphically provided you have enough of the graph available.
- The vertical symmetry axis is $x=x_0$.
- The apex (minimum for $a>0$ resp. maximum if $a<0$) is at $(x_0, y_0)$ with $y_0=a|b|+c$.
- The parabola that's asymptote at the apex has equation $$x\mapsto \frac{a}{2|b|}(x-x_0)^2+y_0$$
- The circle that's asymptote at the apex has radius $|b/a|$, so this quantity can also be determined graphically.
- If you have already determined $a$ and the apex $(x_0,y_0)$, then $h$ is a 1-dimensional family of curves where $b$ and $c$ are related by $y_0=a|b|+c$.

---

**Addendum:** One degree of freedom can easily be added by using exponents other than 2:  Let $b>0$ without loss of generalty, then use $$h(x) = a\big(b^w+|x-x_0|^w\big)^{1/w}+c$$ where $w=2$ is the case of a hyperbola from above.  The formula for apex and the linear asymptotes as $x\to\pm\infty$ stay the same.